# Hosting WebAPI as application inside WebForms in IIS gives 500 error

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have a Webforms application which is hosted in IIS on my local machine. This works fine and there are no issues with this site itself. 
I have now created a WebAPI that I want to sit on the same domain as a ‘folder’ within the web forms application, so I have added a new application within the WebForms site in IIS and pointed it to this WebAPI. The API, in standalone mode (i.e. running direct from VS) works fine, but when I try to access it via the Webforms site (e.g. www.webformssite.com/iis-applciation-name/api/test) I get a generic 500 Internal server error response and absolutely no detail. If I hit the API directly within IIS (as a separate site) it also works fine so its only when accessing it as an IIS application.

I've tried using a new app pool for the WebAPI application and re-using an existing one but it makes no difference.

I’ve read lots of SO questions about the same issue (i.e. 500 error returned from WebAPI) but nothing has helped. I’ve followed this (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/exception-handling) guide too and implemented a global exception filter, put a breakpoint on that and again nothing gets hit. Also, the global error handler in the parent webforms site never fires either so I dont think that is somehow erroring...

I’m not 100% sure if it’s the parent Webforms site, the WebAPI or my IIS config that’s at fault here. The WebForms and WebAPI are both asp.net 4.0 sites in IIS if that is relevant.

Edit:
I have turned on Failed Request tracing and the only relevant part I can see is:

```
    -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 


ModuleName
AspNetInitializationExceptionModule 

Notification
BEGIN_REQUEST 

HttpStatus
500 

HttpReason
Internal Server Error 

HttpSubStatus
0 

ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0) 

ConfigExceptionInfo
```

Nothing else in the failed request trace seems to have any hint of a problem/error!?!

Any hints/suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: If you look in the Event Log on the server, do you see any exceptions related to your Web API site?

Comment: Hi Mason. Thanks for this. DOH. Didn't think to check there! Led me to the problem though and it was the http handlers and modules  in the parent config file interfering with the child application.